# Build apk in c# application?

Tags: android, ant

So im making a C# application which I want to be like a small configuration GUI where the user can input his own parameters and select some features, and according to those a xml file will be made and put in a prebuilt ready-to-build android project (in the asset folder). Now i'm struggling with the part where the C# application should compile the project and make a final apk. I tried to use ant but fail hard at understanding how to use it. Any help would be appreciated, but please be detailed im new to this kind of stuff.

Comment: The android Framework targets java (there is a project allowing to use c# instead, but I advise you to stick with java). Have a look at the tutorials on the official android dev website.

Comment: I can code the GUI in java as well, I just need to know how to do the compiling part which I failed hard with the command line method (I thought I could make a .bat script since I saw some command line methods online, but I couldnt make any to work on my end... )

Comment: @Teovald - this is about using C# to configure, then cause the build of what appears to be a normal Java-based Android project.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Exactly.

Comment: Using something like ant or maven or gradle, it would probably be worth separating the problem into getting to the point where you can cause a build from the command line.  Then figuring out how to execute that command at the request of the C# program -probably C#'s equivalent of the system() or, with a bit more care exec(), calls.  Both subproblems should have a number of existing questions here you could reference.

Comment: my bad, I thought you described the Android app you were trying to do. With Stack Overflow I would not even be surprised..  
I would suggest you to have a look at gradle. The Android team is very cleary pushing in its direction as the main Android app build system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather old question, but I'm going to answer it with my final solution.

I created a builder in C# by including the free apktool (and required files) in my project, which could decompile and compile an apk.

So what I did was after making my app, decompile it with apk tool, and then include the decompiled project with my c# project. The user generated a config file using the C# application, and it was deployed in the /assets/ folder of my app since my app expected it to be there.

Then I builded it again with apktool and signed using a debug keystore. (debug keystore is default if the user has no idea what that is, another keystore can be selected)

Keep in mind that, for this to work, the end user has to have java SE installed, I listed these 2 as "required" in my application (PC restart after installation recommended):

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html

Hope this helps anyone finding this, rather old, post!